# How can I make an object property be both a function and a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-6

I have seen* something where a certain key can be called both as a variable and as a function.
The variable would return a value, the function would do something functiony.

```
obj.test
// E.g. 16

obj.test(32)
// do something with 32
```

I have no idea what library this was. This is not your typical getter/setter scenario, because then the second one would not be a function but a setter.

Please tell me I'm not crazy.

---

*) If I remember what/where, I probably wouldn't need to ask this question.

---

### I found the solution!

After a comment from **T.J.Crowder** about `toString()` as a final possibility, played around with that and got [exactly what I wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424028/#25426423)** (feel free to upvote as well ;)). But what I *wanted* is subjective, and what I *asked* is not. **T.J.Crowder** answered to the best of his ability for all (?) scenarios that someone else with a similar question might want, and therefore I accepted his answer.

**) After grepping `toString` in all libraries I'm using, I found that [Raphael](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.js) does something similar.

Comment: I am sure this is not possible!

Comment: I don't think you can do this in JavaScript.

Comment: it's only me if I'm not understanding...

Comment: "would not be a function but a setter." Why can't a function be a setter?

Comment: *"I have seen something where a certain key can be called both as a variable and as a function..."* Where? If we could see what you're referring to, we could probably help a lot better.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if I remember that, I'm sure I could figure out the answer to this question myself. I remember I found it interesting, and in comments it said something like _This code makes the function double as a variable._

Comment: @Redsandro: That doesn't really answer my question: Where did you see it, and what *exactly* did it look like?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if I would remember where I saw it, I'm sure I could figure out the answer to this question myself. And what I remember is in the question. This doesn't really answer you because I cannot answer your question more specifically. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Redsandro: Ah, gotcha. ("If I *could* remember that..." -- I didn't quite understand you at first.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I _should_, and if I _could_ I _would_. Sorry again for the confusion. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Introduction

If `o.test()` calls a function, then `o.test` returns a function reference, that's a guarantee. Some possible thoughts about what you might have seen:

- If you saw different behavior when something was *assigned* to the property (`obj.test = 42;`) then when it was *retrieved* (`obj.test();`), that might be an *asymmetric property*. More below.
- If `o.test` was being used in some expression, like `var x = o.test + 42;` or `element.innerHTML = o.test;`, it could be they were using an overridden `toString` and/or `valueOf`. More below.
- The property could redefine itself after first use, so `o.test` gives you `16` but then changes the definition of the `o.test` property. More on properties redefining themselves below.

### An asymmetric property

In a comment you've said:

> ... in comments it said something like *This code makes the function double as a variable.*

The closest I can see to that is where you *assign* to it (not read from it) and it remembers the value. That looks like this:

```
var o = {};
(function(obj) {
    var storedValue;

    function weirdFunction(val) {
        return arguments.length === 0 ? storedValue : val;
    }

    Object.defineProperty(obj, "test", {
        get: function() {
            return weirdFunction;
        },
        set: function(value) {
            storedValue = value;
        },
        enumerable: true
    });
})(o);

o.test = 16;
console.log(o.test());   // 16
console.log(o.test(32)); // 32
console.log(o.test());   // 16

o.test = 24;
console.log(o.test());   // 24
console.log(o.test(32)); // 32
console.log(o.test());   // 24
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/vifezo/1)

That's an example of an asymmetric property: When you *read* it, it's always a function; but when you *write* it, you can write any value and it will remember it. I've made the function it gives you when you return it use the stored value unless you give it something else to work with.

There may be good use cases for asymmetric properties, but if so I expect they're few and far between. (For instance, the `document.cookie` property in browsers is an asymmetric property, and it confusese people no end and is a royal pain in the rear to use; a classis case of "wow, they really, really shouldn't have done it like that"...)

### The `toString` / `valueOf` trick

Here's the example of the `toString` / `valueOf` trick (I wouldn't recommend it, but it works with certain caveats):

```
var obj = {test: function(val) { return val; }};
obj.test.valueOf = obj.test.toString = function() {
  return 16;
};
console.log(obj.test);     // 16
console.log(obj.test(32)); // 32
```

It requires that whatever is using the property as a non-function do something to convert it, as `console.log` does (for me on Chrome). E.g., convert it to a string or a number: `var str = "The result is " + obj.test;` (which calls `toString` implicitly), or `var = 5 + obj.test;` (which calls `valueOf` implicitly). If the value is used unconverted, then (of course) it's a function reference.

### Redefining Itself

Another truly horrible thing a property can do, on ES5-compliant systems, is *redefine itself* when it's used:

```
// Truly Evil And Wrong
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "test", {
    get: function() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "test", {
            value: function(val) { return val; },
            enumerable: true
        });
        return 16;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
console.log(obj.test);     // 16
console.log(obj.test);     // function(val) { return val; }
console.log(obj.test(32)); // 32
```

But don't do that. Just don't. :-)

Comment: That's what I would've thought as well, but `console.log(obj.test)` will log a function object, not `16`

Comment: @Bergi: Not on Chrome (as I highlighted). I was slightly surprised, actually.

Comment: So am I :-o Must enquire why…

Comment: @Bergi: INteresting... I'm on Linux, but surely it wouldn't matter...? How are you testing? I'm using the console. If you're using jsFiddle or similar, beware that some of them redefine `console`...

Comment: No no, I can reproduce this in Chrome. Opera works as expected. Digging through Chrome code now :-)

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I will play around with it. _"But don't do that. Just don't. :-)"_ Why not? If this is `ES5` only, that's no problem for a `V8` solution (e.g. `NodeJS`). So `Don't do that` is depending on your case. Correct?

Comment: @Redsandro: Having a property redefine itself on use screams "maintainability problem" and "hard-to-find timing-related bugs" to me. :-) I've added a third thought at the top of the answer, based on your comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting stuff. But in the latest example `o.test` returns the function in stead of the value. I'm starting to doubt if I remember this correctly, but I'm still more sure than unsure.

Comment: @Redsandro: If `o.test()` calls a function, then `o.test` returns a function reference, that's a guarantee (barring the property redefining itself). So the only way `o.test` could *seem* to be something else would be the `toString` / `valueOf` trick.

Comment: I think this comment might be exactly the answer.

Comment: @Redsandro: Yeah, I really should have opened with that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I might imagine is, that 'obj' is redefined later.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with the comment by **T.J.Crowder** mentioning the only way to circumvent returning a function reference is to play with `toString`/`valueOf`. I got something that might be exactly what I saw:

```
var obj = {
    test: (function() {
        var storedValue = 'Nothing. Pass me a number.';

        var doSomething = function(val) {
            storedValue = val;
            return val + ' black rainbows';
        }

        doSomething.toString = function() {
            return storedValue;
        }

        return doSomething;
    })()
};
```

Effectively:

```
obj.test // Nothing. Pass me a number.
obj.test(45) // "45 black rainbows"
obj.test // 45
```

It's just not a settable variable, but I think it's reasonable to assume I made that part up after seeing this. However, maybe some setter trickery is possible to achieve this too.